# how to send message from django server to a nodejs server and receive the reply?

Tags: python, node.js, django

Actually on the django server I have my website server running and on the nodejs server there is a bot which is running. I want my website to communicate with the bot forth and back. How can I achieve this? (for example: my bot accepts a trade given a list of items match to that trade and my website provides that list. So when I click a button my website will send the list to the bot and the bot will operate using that list)

Answer (score 2):

You can use http and websockets like @avril-lavigne said but for me best way to use Message queue (MQ) for example `https://redis.io` since it has [pub\sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) implememtation or maybe best for you [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python).

1. Easiest way:   Send list of items to nodeJs server from the web
   page, process data and send result to webserver using
   websockets/long polling or just hit server every `n` second while
   data not ready and send back to user same way.
2. Good way(for me) make api by Node js, communicate with nodeJs by
   RestApi(idea exactly like in 3th approach by use http).
3. Hard way:    In django you need create a task(your items with
   uniq id to indentify) to put the task to any storage (redis, your
   DB), send that task_id to web_page.

   In that time in nodeJs make a waiter which will wait for the task,
   process the data and put to storage.

   So you have task_id in browser client and ready data in storage. Now
   doing exactly same like in step 1 - hit every n second/* server to
   check if the task is complicated.

Comment: can you help me where can I find the tutorial which can help me understand that?

Comment: @GulshanJangid not sure about tutorials, but updated the answer, maybe it will hit you on your own idea